# doing a verify on void method using powerMock

Tags: powermock

There is a local instance of a class being instantiated inside a method.
eg

```
  class TestMe{
     public void foo()
     {
       A a = new A();
       a.setState(this);
     }
    }




class A
{
    private B b;

    public void setState(TestMe tm)
    {
        b.doSomething(); //returns void
        b.doSomethingAdditional(); //returns void
    }
}
```

When testing foo, using powerMock, I wanted to do a verify to ensure that methods doSomething() and doSomethingAdditional() are called. I was looking something along the lines of the Mockito.verify(ObjectName).functionName() to do. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerMock works in combination with Mockito.  You should still have all the functionality to verify using Mockito calls.

Once you mock `B`, when you mock its functions and then pass it into `A` you can use the `Mockito.verify`.

```
verify(mockBObject).doSomething();
verify(mockBObject).doSomethingAdditional();
```

This may need a few extra steps to hook your mock object into `A`, since you don't have a constructor where you can define `B` passed in, or have some constructor to hook into.  If you are just having `A` initialize `B` at the creation of `A`, you can use some PowerMockito tools to tell it what to do.  Just mocking `B` will not do, because when your `A` is setup, it doesn't know to use your mocked object in its code as the `B` internal.

`PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockBObject);`

As of right now `B` is never setup or initialized, so it could cause some issues.  If `B` is a static singleton object that you are assuming is created somewhere else, you can do similar mocking of the static `getInstance()` call to return a mock of `B`.

Comment: thank you for the helpful comments. I looked at the code in question and unfortunately B does not have a setter method. its constructed locally, used to do a few tasks, and then gc'd. Is there any work around to this then?

Comment: How does B get initialized in your actual code.  Does A create a new one in some kind of setup function?  If B is null on the first time A tries to use it, does it make a new B then?  What pattern do you use.

Comment: inside setState, B is constructed and the functions are called.

Comment: You can use the `PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockBObject);` call to get a mock hooked in.  You can have it with args, and this even works with Statics (a little trickier).  But this is the way to go.

Comment: Powermock is really powerfull, but i'll try to improve the code using dependency injection, so you can pass a mock of B. Pass B in a constructor (as @Walls said), or create a setter for B, or create a factory method for B.